# Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change

Tags: javascript, npm, meteor

```
=> Started MongoDB.                           
W20210705-14:19:04.925(7)? (STDERR) /Users/alexio/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.2.cvynt8.js8ni++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
W20210705-14:19:05.013(7)? (STDERR)       throw error;
W20210705-14:19:05.014(7)? (STDERR)       ^
W20210705-14:19:05.014(7)? (STDERR) 
W20210705-14:19:05.014(7)? (STDERR) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'assets/app/fixtures/hyundai_products.json'
W20210705-14:19:05.014(7)? (STDERR)     at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
W20210705-14:19:05.015(7)? (STDERR)     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
W20210705-14:19:05.015(7)? (STDERR)     at apps/common/helpers/server/getPrivateFile.js:3:26
W20210705-14:19:05.016(7)? (STDERR)     at module (apps/commerce/startup/server/hyundai/fixtures_Product.js:17:31)
W20210705-14:19:05.016(7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210705-14:19:05.016(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210705-14:19:05.016(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/alexio/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.1vgf3j2.535sj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210705-14:19:05.017(7)? (STDERR)     at module (apps/commerce/startup/server/hyundai/index.js:2:1)
W20210705-14:19:05.017(7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210705-14:19:05.017(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210705-14:19:05.017(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/alexio/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.1vgf3j2.535sj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at module (apps/commerce/startup/server/index.js:1:1)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/alexio/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.16.0.1vgf3j2.535sj++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at module (server/main.js:1:1)
W20210705-14:19:05.018(7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20210705-14:19:05.019(7)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20210705-14:19:05.019(7)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)
W20210705-14:19:05.019(7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/alexio/Desktop/catalyst_commerce/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:80210:15
W20210705-14:19:05.019(7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/alexio/Desktop/catalyst_commerce/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:401:38
W20210705-14:19:05.019(7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) {
W20210705-14:19:05.023(7)? (STDERR)   errno: -2,
W20210705-14:19:05.024(7)? (STDERR)   syscall: 'open',
W20210705-14:19:05.024(7)? (STDERR)   code: 'ENOENT',
W20210705-14:19:05.024(7)? (STDERR)   path: 'assets/app/fixtures/hyundai_products.json'
W20210705-14:19:05.025(7)? (STDERR) }
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I've done meteor npm install, but it still doesn't work
I also did npm install all dependencies
Should I reinstall my meteor?
The codes are all cloned from github.

Comment: Hi @SVJA your app tries to open a file which does not exist.  Make sure the file exists in the project. Note, that Meteor resolves filepaths diofferent from other node apps. Also note that you can directly `import` a json file. No need to use `readFileSync` here!

Answer (score 0):

You'd usually want to look at the first error message line. Just before the trace:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'assets/app/fixtures/hyundai_products.json'

Then use the stack trace to find the code.

Comment: From how I am reading it you should look inside: apps/common/helpers/server/getPrivateFile.js for where you are importing assets/app/fixtures/hyundai_products.json and check that the path is correct.